# CodeIgniter Active Records Help needed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to find out the latest image uploaded in each of the category of a website from the data base where the structure of the database is :

tbl_cat : cat_id, cat_name, noi (no. of total images in that cat)
tbl_img : img_id, cat_id, img_path, imag_caption

Any idea how can I do it using active records. I would also love to understand it with sql query. I know its lame, but I am just starting. Sorry about that.

Comment: Are you recording in the database the time at which each image was uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database schema given does not record the creation date in either the category or image tables. The only legitimate way I can think to obtain this information is to command line `cd` into the images directory and perform a `ls --full-time --sort=time` (on Debian based systems) or it's equivalent.

**Update 1 after comments:**

Run: `SELECT c.cat_id, c.cat_name, i.doc, i.img_path FROM tbl_cat c LEFT JOIN tbl_img i ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id WHERE doc = (SELECT MAX(doc) FROM tbl_img i2 WHERE i2.cat_id = c.cat_id`

Comment: Sorry, I thought the time field won't be required, I have stored the date of creation for the image ! So how can we use it ?

Comment: Where have you stored the creation date of the image? Your schema as you've said is: "tbl_img : img_id, cat_id, img_path, imag_caption"

Comment: there is another field called 'doc' in the tbl_img

Comment: Yea? And what are some examples in the `doc` column?

Comment: the date and time of the image creation in the format : 2012-06-20 12:07:00

Comment: Try this SQL: `SELECT c.cat_id, c.cat_name, i.doc, i.img_path FROM tbl_cat c LEFT JOIN tbl_img i ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id WHERE doc = (SELECT MAX(doc) FROM tbl_img i2 WHERE i2.cat_id = c.cat_id)`

Comment: Thank you so much @Jordan Arseno, It worked ! Can you help me with my another problem in redirecting my old website url using 301 here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284259/301-htaccess-redirect-with-codeigniter/12284378#comment16478098_12284378

Comment: I did that, very new to StackOverflow, learning things here. Thanks anyways :)