# 301 redirect for old pages of the website with codeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have just now upgraded one of my static website to a codeIgniter enabled website. I need to redirect the exact domain names of the old website to the new ones to avoid the 404 error.

- Old pages > `http://example.com/pagename.php`
- New pages > `http://example.com/index.php/home/category_images/9(cat_id)`

I do not a very high no. of pages so hard coding all the pages directly will not be a problem. I have tried :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com/pagename.php$ http://example.com/index.php/home/category_images/9 [L,R=301]
```

Not working, I have no idea why. `mod_rewrite` is enable on my apache server.

Also, just for the confirmation please also tell me in which folder I should put this file, I am confused between root dir or Application folder.

Thank you.

Version 2 : Now after suggestion from Mr. Michael, I tried to implement it using the redirect function like this :

Default Controller function : home.php

```
function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('common_model');
    $this->handle_redirects();
}

function handle_redirects () 
{
    $redirects = Array(
    'gorgeous-girls.php' => 'home/category_images/9'
    );
    $uri = implode('/', $this->uri->segments);
    foreach ($redirects as $from => $to)
    {
        $from = str_replace(':any', '.+', str_replace(':num', '[0-9]+', $from));
        if (preg_match("#^{$from}$#i", $uri))
        {
        if (strpos($to, '$') !== false and strpos($from, '(') !== false)
            $to = preg_replace("#^{$from}$#i", $to, $uri);
        redirect($to , 'location', 301);
        }
    }
}
```

And my .htaccess looks like :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

PS : I have removed index.php from my domain name structure. It looks like : www.example.com/controller/function/uri/uri

Now I am not getting an error page from my host, but I am getting an error page from the CodeIgniter.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that your Hypertext Access file should be routing everything through **`index.php`** anyway, it is best to handle your redirects using CodeIgniter's **`redirect()`** function.

An example is provided below, based on what I have in my *Page* controller, in my own framework extensions (it can be used anywhere where the **`redirect()`** function is available, as well as **`$this->uri->segments`**.

```
function handle_redirects () {
    $redirects = Array(
        'pagename.php' => 'home/category_images/9'
    );
    $uri = implode('/', $this->uri->segments);
    foreach ($redirects as $from => $to)
    {
        $from = str_replace(':any', '.+', str_replace(':num', '[0-9]+', $from));
        if (preg_match("#^{$from}$#i", $uri))
        {
            if (strpos($to, '$') !== false and strpos($from, '(') !== false)
                $to = preg_replace("#^{$from}$#i", $to, $uri);
            redirect($to , 'location', 301);
        }
    }
}
```

If you were to pass a query to your **`pagename.php`** file in your framework, you could consider the following (note that I do not know what the intention of your pages are - this is a generic solution):

```
$redirects = Array(
    'pagename.php?q=(:any)' => 'home/category_images/$1'
);
```

For example:

```
http://example.com/pagename.php?q=9
```

would redirect you to:

```
http://example.com/home/category_images/9
```

This solution works for me quite well, and is very efficient when it comes to cross-browser compatibility.

Note that your RewriteRules should look like this, or something similar to it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (xml|txt|css|js|jpg|png|gif)$ - [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

> **Edit**: The above has been changed to accommodate for assets. Basically, it tells Apache to route everything through `index.php`, unless it is a file that exists AND has the extensions specified. (This is good practice for security purposes.)
>
> **Edit**: Note that you should not include `index.php` in your URL as it is being stripped by the `.htaccess` file anyway.

Note that I use PHP 5.3 - though this solution should work for you. Please let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: Sir, I am very new to codeIgniter and even to PHP, I have not removed the index.php from my domain name, does that mean everything is routed through it ?

Comment: And also, please tell me how do I use this, home.php is my default controller, so should I just make another function with this code anywhere in home.php anywhere, or do i need to do anything specific. Also, how do I call this function ? My usecase is, the domains I want to redirect are static page from my old website, which has good seo, and a lot of people coming to them everyday, and I do not need to pass any query to the old page.

Comment: @Vinay: For SEO purposes, everything should be routed through index.php. If your rewrite rules look the same as I have posted them, then place the function in your home controller. Then, in the controllers construct function, add $this->handle_redirects(). Once the function is working, you can simply add the rules to the $redirects array. By using these redirects, you are kindly telling search engines that you've changed your URI structure, and you status on these search engines should remain the same. Do let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: Sir, I did exactly you told me to do, It is not working. I have tried almost everything I could find on different blogs by googling for this issue. It is not getting resolved ! :( :(

Comment: @Vinay: Perhaps if you share your implementation of my proposed answer (by editing your question -- perhaps others may know of a better solution based obn mine), and tell me if it is throwing any errors at you.

Comment: I have posted the code implementation of your solution and edited the question. See if you can help me !

Comment: Vinay, you would be getting the 404 error if you include `index.php` in the request URI, because all URI's are being routed through that file anyway. You should leave that out of the URL altogether: http://example.com/georgeous-girls.php (which would take you to the destination), not http://example.com/index.php/georgeous-girls.php. As for your asset files, I will post a solution for you in the morning (I am using my mobile to post these comments). Using the Hypertext Access file, you can instruct it to ignore rewriting for files that exist.

Comment: Looks like we made some progress here sir. Earlier I was getting a 404 page from my host website, but now after making there changes, I am getting a 404 page from the codeIgniter ! What do you think we should do now ? 

Also do I need to make any changes to the function handle_redirects() when I use in my controller except the page names in the array ! 

Can I add you to my gmail or something for a faster communication ? (PS : I am not aware of the rules of this website )

Comment: Also, I have removed the index.php from my domain name. using this code : RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: My method already removed the `index.php`. I understand that you are new to all this, but fear that you are not grasping the concept. Nonetheless, your new `.htaccess` file should work much the same (sans a small security issue). As for communicating directly, I would not do it as I won't share my address with the public, and it's better to come to a resolution here so that others can learn from it too.

Comment: I am sorry about that sir, I am trying my level best here !We can discuss it here itself. I just wanted to make it quicker. Now I am stuck at 404 page from codeIgniter, earlier it was 404 page from the server. So what change can we do now to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the whole domain name in the match portion of the rewrite rule.  Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^pagename.php$ /index.php/home/category_images/9 [L,R=301]
```

Of course you will likely need other rules for the server to understand that index.php is the file that is to be called, not something at /image.php/home/category_images/9

So perhaps a second rule like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) /index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

I just noticed that in your updated answer you are trying to redirect from www.example.com to example.com.  If you do want to force one domain, you should probably add another rule in your .htaccess before either of the other rules mentioned like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
Rewrite Rule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This is how my code looks like for the htaccess fiel now and it is still not working ? :( 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
Rewrite Rule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) /index.php?q=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^page-name.php$ /index.php/home/category_images/9 [L,R=301]

And I have placed my .htaccess file in Application folder. Any ideas ?

Comment: @VinaySinghal Are the .htaccess rules not working at all or just some rule?  The reason I ask is that you might need to set you main apache conf file to AllowOverride.  Without this, .htaccess files are just ignored.

Comment: Sir, I am very new to development. I have no idea about this. I don't know which one is working and which one is not. If you ask me I can perform the test. Also the website is hosting on a shared hosting account from 1and1.com

Comment: @VinaySinghal Try this. Type an illegal line at the beginning of the .htaccess file in your web root. Something like `BadDirectiveHere`.  Then try to request any page on the server.  You should get a 500 error.  If you don't, then we will know that your don't have `AllowOverride` turned on.

Comment: I am getting a 500 error sir. When I did this, I got an error and I was not able to access my website. @Mike Brant

Comment: @VinaySinghal Good that means that the htaccess file is being read.  You need to place the .htaccess file in your web root directory.  Just go rule by rule (commenting out the others) to figure out which rules are working the way you want. Of course remove the invalid rule that you used to test htaccess.

Comment: Sir can you check my edits in the question, Now I am trying to do it the other way ! And rather than getting a 404 error page from my host like earlier,  I am getting a 404 page from codeIgniter this time.

Answer (score 0):

you can open you xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf

After then check below line

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

if Hash (#) exist in above the line. then remove it.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and restart your apache server and check you site.

After then site not working please let me know.

Comment: Sir, the mod_rewrite is enables and not commented in this file also, and my website server where I have hosted it, is also enabled it. Still it is not working. Now I am trying : - 

RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ Rewrite Rule ^(.*)$ example.com/$1 [L,R=301] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) /index.php?q=$1 [L] RewriteRule ^page-name.php$ /index.php/home/category_images/9 [L,R=301]

This is also not working sir.